# Handlebar Block wont display products on homepage

Tags: blocks, category-products, ce-1.9.2.3

I've inserted:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/3columns-list.phtml"}}
```

on the homepage cms page.

The products from category 3 **All** display in magento 1.9.1 but the same code does not work for magento 1.9.2.3.

Any ideas what has changed or be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, you have to allow certain block types in magento 1.9.2 or later.

Visit System -> Permissions -> Blocks and in my case added "catalog/product_list"

Cheers